# Reference other Key in Object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this module:

```
exports.yeah = {
   hallo: {
     shine: "was",
     yum: this.hallo.shine
   }
}
```

As you can see I try to reference **shine** in `yum: this.hallo.shine`

**But when I do try to execute my script I get this error:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'shine' of undefined
```

**It seems like that the scope is wrong!**

I tried different things for example `module.exports.yeah.hallo.shine`

**But it simply won't work! How can I fix this error?** 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use javascript [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

```js
var exports = {};
exports.yeah = {
  hallo: {
    shine: "was",
    get yum() {
      return this.shine
    }
  }
};
document.write(exports.yeah.hallo.yum);
```

Note, `this` in the context of the `getter` will refer to `hallo` and not `yeah`

According to the documentation

> The get syntax binds an object property to a function that will be
>   called when that property is looked up.

So since the getter function is called(*looked up*) **after** object initialization, `this` can be used to reference `shine`

**Update**

> Lets say the object is build like that {hallo1: {..}, hallo2: {..} } . And now I want to reference in hallo1.yum = hallo2.shine Is that possible?

Yes, it is possible because at the time of *getting* the object is initialized and you can refer to the object itself rather than `this`

```js
var exports = {};
exports.yeah = {
  hallo1: {
    shine: "was",
    get yum() {
      return exports.yeah.hallo2.yum;
    }
  },
  hallo2: {
    shine: "is",
    get yum() {
      return this.shine;
    }
  }
};
document.write(exports.yeah.hallo1.yum);
```

Comment: Really nice! I didn't know that something like this exists. One Question: Lets say the object is build like that `{hallo1: {..}, hallo2: {..} }` . And now I want to reference in `hallo1.yum = hallo2.shine` Is that possible? Thanks!

Comment: If you can use these, do! They're really good and will make life a lot easier.

Comment: @JohnSmith, sorry I mixed them up to reference `hallo2.yum = hallo1.yum` let me know if you want me to do it exactly how you wanted. But, if you get the picture you should be able to do it the other way.

Answer (score 2):

When you reference `this.hallo`, the VM is still creating the object and hasn't assigned it to `hallo` yet. You need to initialize that field later.

In order to build your example:

```
exports.yeah = {
   hallo: {
     shine: "was",
     yum: this.hallo.shine
   }
}
```

the VM will need to create

```
{
  shine: "was",
  yum: this.hallo.shine
}
```

and assign it to `hallo` as it creates

```
{
   hallo: {
     shine: "was",
     yum: this.hallo.shine
   }
}
```

which it then assigns to `exports.yeah`.

This is much like function parameters being evaluated before the function is called.

When you reference `this.hallo.shine`, that chain has not yet been created. Since you're using object literals, you can't rely on `this.shine` either, since `this` points to the scope.

You need to use late(r) initialization, like:

```
exports.yeah = {
   hallo: {
     shine: "was"
   }
}
exports.yeah.hallo.yum = exports.yeah.hallo.shine;
```